# Reading one file xxx.asp in the main page

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a file with the extension .asp which has 4 strings that I need in my main file. I know that is a beginner question, but, how can I read the file in my main page?

Comment: what kind of variables do you have?

Comment: String paraEmail = "para@email.com.br";
String copiaEmail = "cc@email.com.br";
String copiaOculta = "bcc@email.com.br";
String assuntoEmail = "Device / Monitor";
String corpo = "<html><body style='font-family: Calibri,Candara,Segoe,'Segoe UI',Optima,Arial,sans-serif;font-size:20px;font-style:normal;font-variant:normal;font-weight:500;line-height:22px'><p>Here,<br/><br/>We have a Text<br/><br/></p></body></html>"